# Can I run objects in memory or do I need to look at Serializeing to DB

Tags: c#, multithreading, design-patterns, ooad

I am working on a multithread app that has about 4 basic Entities at its core

e.g

```
 public class Album
{
    public ICPN ICPN { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string PLine { get; set; }
    public string CLine { get; set; }


    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public string SubGenre { get; set; }

    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public int NumTracks { get; set; }
    public int NumVolumes { get; set; }

    public IList<ITerms> Terms { get; set; }

}
```

I have a 4 step process where I am using the Producer/Consumer  Pattern with BlockingCollections to manage these process's. It is a production line and I modify state on a object once complete, make a copy of the stats & enque onto the next process queue where it waits for the next process/task to be preformed.

I am at that critical juncture of architecture design of whethere I need to look at serializing some of the BlockingCollections to DB or can I run with about 10 million objects of the type above in the Pipe on a Highend server.

I have a queue dedicated to stats on each process I.e Timetaken/Success for the UI Or should I look at storeing this info with the objects ?

Speed/Effeciency is crtical in this process.

Are there any ways to calculate Memory requirements or is this a case of suck it & see

**Update** At this stage I dont need to persist the data for crashes etc as the metadata objects are modified and writen out to disk...i.e unprocessed folder/processed folder

Comment: If you want the objects to be persistent then you do need to implement a persistence mechanism. You can you the built in serializers or something like protobuf-net. Storage requirements as well as performance will depend on the serialization technology. Regardless of how powerful the server is, if you want the objects to survive server restarts/crashes, you will need to persist.

Comment: Server restarts/crashes are not an issue @ this point..my question is really how much load can you store in memory from a performance perspective

Comment: I'm not sure why you are asking, and I suspect knowing that would help in producing an actual, helpful answer. It's fairly easy to do some multiplication to get some really rough ideas of memory usage of basic POCO objects; as in, "could I fit thousands, millions, or billions of these in memory at once?" but asking such a question doesn't generally produce a very useful answer.

Comment: Is there any recomended ways of approaching this problem  Should I persist all/some of these queues to DB or can I get away with having all of these occur in memory and rely on the Input/OutPut folders as a measure of the process inr egards to crashes

Comment: If there is a helpful answer please mark it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really describe the form factor of your application, so I'll start by saying that it depends.

If there is ever a need for your application to restart or if there is a remote chance that your application could have bugs in it, then I suggest persisting your live data to some form of data store (database, file, etc) while it is in flight. Of course this only matters if you never want to lose data.

EDIT: Considering your edit, I don't think it is really a necessity unless you want to save off results of any previous processing of the data.